# Downloading Outlook attachments with REST API?

Tags: python, api, email, outlook, hotmail

Im working on a project that is related to the Outlook Mail API. I want to download the attachments an email has.
The documantation says that i can "get" the attachments, and they return different parameters in a json response, but im curious to know which one i have to convert to what, to get the actual attachment saved on to the filesystem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#Getattachments

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the documentation, `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{message_id}/attachments` returns a collection of attachments which contains an identifier for the individual attachment:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/Messages('AAMkAGI2THVSAAA%3D')/Attachments(Name)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
            "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('ddfcd489-628b-40d7-b48b-57002df800e5@1717622f-1d94-4d0c-9d74-709fad664b77')/Messages('AAMkAGI2THVSAAA=')/Attachments('AAMkAGI2j4kShdM=')",
            "Id": "AAMkAGI2j4kShdM=",
            "Name": "minutes.docx"
        }
    ] }
```

Now, you can iterate through this list and fetch individual attachment using this API - `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{message_id}/attachments/{attachment_id}` where attachment_id is the identifier returned from above API.

The response will be:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/Messages('AAMkAGI2THVSAAA%3D')/Attachments/$entity",
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
    "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('ddfcd489-628b-40d7-b48b-57002df800e5@1717622f-1d94-4d0c-9d74-709fad664b77')/Messages('AAMkAGI2THVSAAA=')/Attachments('AAMkAGI2j4kShdM=')",
    "Id": "AAMkAGI2j4kShdM=",
    "LastModifiedDateTime": "2014-10-20T00:41:52Z",
    "Name": "minutes.docx",
    "ContentType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    "Size": 11585,
    "IsInline": false,
    "ContentId": null,
    "ContentLocation": null,
    "ContentBytes": "UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQDCAAA4KQAAAAA=" }
```

Now, you can save this attachment locally using ContentBytes and contentType. Moreover, attachments could be `ItemAttachments` or `FileAttachments`. Searching more on Google will definitely lead you to some sample code which shows how to download them. But this should give you an idea.

You can check this:

```
public static void GetAttachmentsFromEmail(ExchangeService service, ItemId itemId)
        {
            // Bind to an existing message item and retrieve the attachments collection.
            // This method results in an GetItem call to EWS.
            EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, itemId, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Attachments));

            // Iterate through the attachments collection and load each attachment.
            foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
            {
                if (attachment is FileAttachment)
                {
                    FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;

                    // Load the attachment into a file.
                    // This call results in a GetAttachment call to EWS.
                    fileAttachment.Load("C:\\temp\\" + fileAttachment.Name);

                    Console.WriteLine("File attachment name: " + fileAttachment.Name);
                }
                else // Attachment is an item attachment.
                {
                    ItemAttachment itemAttachment = attachment as ItemAttachment;

                    // Load attachment into memory and write out the subject.
                    // This does not save the file like it does with a file attachment.
                    // This call results in a GetAttachment call to EWS.
                    itemAttachment.Load();

                    Console.WriteLine("Item attachment name: " + itemAttachment.Name);
                }
            }
        }
```