# Is there a way to get Attachments url from Microsoft Graph Subscription response?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to include Microsoft Graph API mail subscription in a Javascript project with `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client`, I get an object response (body, subject, cc, to ...etc) and a Boolean `hasAttachments: true` but the attachment url is nowhere to be found, is there a way to get these attachments ?

Comment: What type of attachment is that?

Comment: I tried pictures like ".jpg" and compressed files like ".zip" in both cases i don't get the download url

Comment: Ok i tried this Graph API call using Javascript code and it's working for me (get the .txt file):

const options = {
 authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

let res = await client.api('/me/messages/AAMkAGRlNWM4Njk4LWY3NTYtNGE2MC05ZjQzLTg1YmM5YjIzNTRhMwBGAAAAAAA-L78mmzKFQ7FpvCcWkAziBwCUgufVfU8cSKxkYzIkrl81AAAAAAEMAACUgufVfU8cSKxkYzIkrl81AACABFjMAAA=/attachments/AAMkAGRlNWM4Njk4LWY3NTYtNGE2MC05ZjQzLTg1YmM5YjIzNTRhMwBGAAAAAAA-L78mmzKFQ7FpvCcWkAziBwCUgufVfU8cSKxkYzIkrl81AAAAAAEMAACUgufVfU8cSKxkYzIkrl81AACABFjMAAABEgAQAHhM4mZxBRNBqkVbYUzUcWA=')
 .get();

Comment: I get something like this `{
    "@odata.context": "xxxxxx",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
    "@odata.mediaContentType": "application/zip",
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-10-12T11:08:37Z",
    "name": "xxxxx.zip",
    "contentType": "application/zip",
    "size": 77067,
    "isInline": false,
    "contentId": null,
    "contentLocation": null,
    "contentBytes": "UEsDBBQACAAIADt8NVEAAAAAAAAAAA+HAQAOAC.......etc"
}`

Comment: @Dev i can't see the url, do you convert the ContentBytes ?

Comment: so you want to convert the contentbytes and store it locally, then please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54820844/download-attachments-from-mail-using-microsoft-graph-rest-api

Comment: Let me know whether the above helps you or not.

Comment: @Dev Thank you very much it answered all my problems ! :)

Comment: Aaw, thank you so much for your kind words @Garsivirus. I am glad that my answers helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i tried this Graph API call using Javascript code and it's working for me (get the .txt file):

```js
const options = { authProvider, }; 
const client = Client.init(options); 
let res = await client.api('/me/messages/AAMkAGRlNWM4Njk4LWY3NTYtNGE2MC05ZjQzLTg1YmM5YjIzNTRhMwBGAAAAAAA-L78mmzKFQ7FpvCcWkAziBwCUgufVfU8cSKxkYzIkrl81AAAAAAEMAACUgufVfU8cSKxkYzIkrl81AACABFjMAAA=/attachments/AAMkAGRlNWM4Njk4LWY3NTYtNGE2MC05ZjQzLTg1YmM5YjIzNTRhMwBGAAAAAAA-L78mmzKFQ7FpvCcWkAziBwCUgufVfU8cSKxkYzIkrl81AAAAAAEMAACUgufVfU8cSKxkYzIkrl81AACABFjMAAABEgAQAHhM4mZxBRNBqkVbYUzUcWA=').get();
```

and to convert the contentbytes and store it locally refer the related link - [download attachments from mail using microsoft graph rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54820844/download-attachments-from-mail-using-microsoft-graph-rest-api) as well.

Answer (score 2):

when you got the message
try this url
GET /me/messages/{id}/attachments/{id}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).